# How can I quickly copy large files off of a laptop when booted off a LiveCD?

Tags: windows, samba

Yesterday I received a laptop that would not boot and i needed to get the pictures and documents off of it. I booted into Ubuntu with a Live CD (installing is out of the question) and zipped up all of his files. It wrapped up to about 5.3 GB.

I decided i should burn 2 DVD's for him but since I was running off a Live CD, i could not. Also his USB Ports and Ethernet port are busted. So I tried to change the hard drive to a shared folder but it would not change the permissions. None of the fixes have worked, since I'm on a Live CD. I just need to transfer my zip from one computer to another. Cloud storage won't work either.

Help me!!

Comment: You're saying everything but the network, monitor, keyboard, and mouse are busted?

Comment: Yes, it is a very old laptop. It is very slow and every time it goes to sleep the whole thing freezes and i have to force reboot it.

Comment: Try my answer. It is not with Samba, but that did inspire me. This is just a makeshift solution and you shouldn't rely on it for secure data transfer through a network(very open privileges) but it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It will work great... if the laptop doesn't go to sleep :P

Comment: This is a nice story, however this seems to be a support's place, not a bar. BTW: The solution for your problem is purchase a new laptop or at least the motherboard and inner components. Anyway, it was funny reading all your excited written's stuff.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easiest to simply pull the hard drive and put it in a more functional computer? It's dead easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a Windows machine as an FTP server to transfer files to:

Download [FileZilla Server](http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server) on the Windows machine and install it. Leave all settings default. Then, go to the Filezilla administration interface:

[image]

and enter the Users dialog. Add a user, remembering the username and password, and give it a directory on the Shared Folders tab. Give the user read, write, delete,append access to files, and allow this user to create subdirectories and list them. You now have a user set up. Close the dialog.

[image]

You can now try to access the FTP server(on your local network, with the IP address of the server machine and port 21. Do this using Nautilus. When you copy files there, they will end up on the Windows machine, in that user's folder.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I am transferring the files now. Only 5 hours to go... :P

Comment: 5 hours to transfer 5GB?

Comment: @TomBrossman It appears to be over a LAN.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu One gives you 5 GB, not quite what you need. But you might try uploading the files in two batches.

I'm sorry I don't know a better solution with only a CD drive.

Comment: I am not sure exactly if I can do that, since I need to get the file from his hard drive. I am mainly just looking to transfer it to another computer with a dvd burner.

Comment: Ubuntu One (https://one.ubuntu.com/) is a cloud storage service that you can access from your Live CD, but I think the other answers below are much better solutions for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can share a folder from a working computer that the laptop can then write into.  That would be similar to the ftp/filezilla answer above, but wouldn't require installing any additional software.  Moving the file could then be done with drag and drop in the nautilus file manager.

Comment: Yeah I didn't think of creating the shared folder on the working computer. Thanks for the answer.